# Does bash have its own echo, printf, [ functions?

Tags: bash, shell

when I trace output of the of nice.sh script with strace, I see tons of child processes.

```
strace -ff -o nice.o ./nice.sh
```

nice.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

while /usr/bin/[ 1 ]
do
    echo ..;
done;
```

On the other hand if I run the script below, I do not see any forked child process:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ 1 ]
do
    echo ..;
done;
```

The same is also true for echo, /bin/echo and printf, /usr/bin/printf. Does it mean that  some commands are embedded into bash? If yes, what are the other commands?

Comment: Type `info bash`, then go to the "Shell Builtin Commands" section or see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands). Please consider consulting the manual before posting here.

Comment: Most Bourne-derived shells have these commands builtin. The external versions were once useful with shells that didn't have them builtin. They are sometimes still useful with complex `find` or `xargs` commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, bash, and the other shells each have numerous builtins.

[Here's](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) the list for bash with accompanying documentation for each builtin.

Comment: `$ type [ echo printf`
`[ is a shell builtin`
`echo is a shell builtin`
`printf is a shell builtin`

Comment: @mertinan: `enable -a` will show you all the builtins and whether they are enabled. `type -a command` will show you how a command is defined in preferential order.